# Conflito entre JBoss BOM e Demoiselle parent pom (?)

Tags: demoiselle

Olá,

minha aplicação Demoiselle declara o seguinte para ser uma aplicação Demoiselle:

```
<properties>
    <demoiselle.framework.version>2.5.0-RC1</demoiselle.framework.version>
</properties>

<parent>
    <groupId>br.gov.frameworkdemoiselle</groupId>
    <artifactId>demoiselle-servlet-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.0-RC1</version>
</parent>
```

Ao fazer isso, entendo que o pom pai de minha aplicação passa a ser esse: http://maven-repository.com/artifact/br.gov.frameworkdemoiselle/demoiselle-servlet-parent/2.5.0/pom_effective

Nesse cara tem várias dependências listadas na seção dependencyManagement. Qual a relação dessas dependências com minha aplicação? Elas não são incorporadas automaticamente à aplicação, neh? E quando eu declaro uma dependência como demoiselle-jpa (que já está no pom pai), eu não preciso declarar versão porque o Maven vai puxar a versão do pom pai, certo?

Agora complicando... no pom da aplicação temos também o seguinte:

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.bom</groupId>
            <artifactId>eap6-supported-artifacts</artifactId>
            <version>6.3.0.GA</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

Isso faz referência a um arquivo BOM da Red Hat que lista todas as biblitoecas disponíveis no JBoss EAP 6.3*. Assim, dado que minha aplicação vai utilizar o JBoss EAP 6.3, eu não preciso me preocupar em conhecer as versões exatas das bibliotecas JavaEE (cdi, jsf etc etc).

* Arquivo BOM: http://maven.repository.redhat.com/techpreview/all/org/jboss/bom/eap6-supported-artifacts/6.3.0.GA/eap6-supported-artifacts-6.3.0.GA.pom

Agora a questão: **algumas dessas bibliotecas (ex: weld-core) aparecem tanto no arquivo BOM quanto no Demoiselle parent. Isso é um problema?** Nesse caso, como essas dependências do JavaEE são marcadas com scope provided, sei que em tempo de execução a aplicação vai utilizar as versões disponíveis no JBoss. Mas em outros contextos (compilação, testes unitários) de quem o maven vai puxar as dependências? Do BOM ou do Demoiselle parent? Existe algum tipo de conflito de versão ao tentar incluir bibliotecas de versões diferentes?

Por fim, qual a necessidade de se utilizar o Demoiselle parent pom? Não seria melhor ir adicionando as bibliotecas do Demoiselle necessárias ao seu projeto uma por uma, de forma a ter somente o necessário?

Desculpem se as questões ficaram complexas, mas o objetivo último último é realizar a gerência de dependências do meu projeto da melhor forma possível, evitando qualquer risco de conflitos de versão ou versões diferentes utilizadas em contextos diferentes.

Muito obrigado!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Desculpe a demora na resposta, mas estava ocupado esses dias.

Vou responder as questões para que não fique na dúvida, mas no final tem a solução correta para o seu cenário.

Quanto as questões:

Q: algumas dessas bibliotecas (ex: weld-core) aparecem tanto no arquivo BOM quanto no Demoiselle parent. Isso é um problema? Nesse caso, como essas dependências do JavaEE são marcadas com scope provided, sei que em tempo de execução a aplicação vai utilizar as versões disponíveis no JBoss.

R: Não é problema aparecer nas duas, pois é justamente o papel do Maven resolver os conflitos de acordo com o que você mesmo configurar no manven.  Em tempo de execução vai utilizar o que estiver no servidor como vc mesmo já entendeu.

Q: Mas em outros contextos (compilação, testes unitários) de quem o maven vai puxar as dependências? Do BOM ou do Demoiselle parent? Existe algum tipo de conflito de versão ao tentar incluir bibliotecas de versões diferentes?

R: Depende do contexto, na compilação (por ser provided) não influência, mas nos testes de unidade será aquela informada no POM.XML que por sua vez estará no repositório local. As bibliotecas nos Parent do Demoiselle são definidas para ajudar justamente a não ter tanta coisa repetida em várias aplicações e que podem ser um padrão, mas qualquer dependência pode ser incluida ou excluida através do POM.XML de acordo com a vontade do desenvolvedor, basta configurar no arquivo. Usar diferentes entre o provided e o que está no teste de unidade, pode (não é certeza do sim nem do não) ser problema, pois não garante que o que foi testado irá executar exatamente da mesma forma no servidor.

Bom, como disse a solução para seu caso deve ser essa:

A diferença está em usar o JBoss EAP 6.3, enquanto o que está sendo previsto como default nos Parents do Demoiselle é o JBoss AS 7.1.x da comunidade. Neste caso, o que falta é você definir um PROFILE para EAP.
O profile padrão do Demoiselle é: JBoss7 que se refere ao AS 7.1.x, e exitem também Tomcat7 e até mesmo outros de versões mais antigas do Jboss e Tomcat. Tem também para Glassfish e WebLogic. Bastaria no Eclipse selecionar qual.
Por isso é que você terá que criar um profile para EAP, depois selecionar no Eclipse esse profile. Onde acho (não uso EAP), que vai ter apenas a dependência que citou:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.bom</groupId>
        <artifactId>eap6-supported-artifacts</artifactId>
        <version>6.3.0.GA</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Pode também sugerir a inclusão deste profile nos padrões do Demoiselle: http://tracker.frameworkdemoiselle.gov.br

E não tem do que se desculpar, pois todo questionamento sempre ajuda a melhorar o projeto.

Exemplo no POM

[image: Profile no pom]

Selecionando pelo Eclipse
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Muito obrigado pela resposta detalhada!
Acho que só não entendi direito que "profile" é esse... profile do Maven não é, né? Seria um "profile do Eclipse"? Como eu busco mais sobre esse profile? Obrigado!

Comment: O profile é uma configuração do Maven. Veja neste arquivo os profiles padrões do Demoiselle: https://github.com/demoiselle/framework/blob/master/parent/servlet/pom.xml      No seu caso você pode fazer a configuração no POM.XML do projeto. Para que isso funcione no Eclipse, caso não for usar o padrão (no caso do Demoiselle é o Jboss AS 7), é preciso selecionar o profile. No menu do Eclipse(selecionando o projeto) é: Maven -> Select Maven Profile...

Comment: Oi! Não consegui descobrir como ativar o profile só editando meu pom. Tem jeito? Vi que daria pra fazer com o settings.xml ou passando o -P no comando mvn. Mas no pom mesmo não achei.

Comment: Quando incluir no POM deve aparecer como uma opação no Eclipse: Ctrl+Alt+P. Vou editar a resposta para exemplificar.